# Appearance of "Fat Spiders" in Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

When investigating the properties of least detours of edges in complete, weighted graphs, I noticed an interesting phenomenon in the visualization of graphs where the nodes correspond to points in the Euclidean plane and edge-weights to Euclidean distances between points.
Out of curiosity, I depicted the edges $e_{ij}$, that satisfy $$\ k^*\notin \lbrace i,j\rbrace\ \wedge\ \forall k\notin \lbrace i,j\rbrace:\  \|e_{ik^*}\|+\|e_{k^*j}\|\ \le\ \|e_{ik}\|+\|e_{kj}\| \quad \implies \|e_{ik^*}\|\gt \|e_{ij}\|\ \lor\ \|e_{k^*j}\|\gt \|e_{ij}\|$$

Here is a visualization of an instance with 3000 points:
[image: image of a graph with fat spiders]

> **Questions:**
>
> Let "fat spiders" denote vertices with exceptionally high degree, that have noticable appearance in visualizations of a graph.
>
> - is there an explanation for the appearance of the "**fat spiders**" in certain spanners of complete weighted graphs obtained from points that are iid in a square of the Euclidean plane?
> - are fat spiders a widespread phenomen of complete weigthed graphs or does their appearance depend on special conditions?

the code with wich the graph has been generated, is given below:

> [Processing](http://www.processing.org) code for the generating the depicted graph:

```
int n=3000;  
float[] x = new float[n];  
float[] y = new float[n];  
float[][]  dst = new float[n][n];  
boolean[][] flag = new boolean[n][n];  

void setup(){  
  fullScreen();  
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {  
    x[i]=random(height)*0.9+width/2-0.45*height; }  
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){  
    y[i]=random(height)*0.9+0.05*height;  
    dst[i][i] = 0;  
    flag[i][i] = false;}  
  for (int i=1; i<n; ++i){  
    for (int j=0; j<i; ++j){  
      dst[i][j] = dst[j][i] = dist(x[i],y[i],x[j],y[j]);  
      flag[i][j] = flag[j][i] = false;}}  

  for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) {  
    for (int j=0; j<i; ++j) {  
      float min_dt = MAX_FLOAT;  
      int min_k  = -1;  
      for (int k=0; k<n; ++k){  
        if (k==i || k==j) {  
          continue; }  
        float dt = dst[i][k]+dst[k][j];  
        if (dt < min_dt) {  
          min_dt = dt;  
          min_k  = k;}}  
      // --- SELECTION CRITERION FOR EDGES --- 
      if (dst[i][min_k] > dst[i][j] ||  dst[min_k][j] > dst[i][j]) {  
        flag[i][j] = flag[j][i] = true;}}}  
  background(255);  
  fill(255,0,0);  
  strokeWeight(1);  
  stroke(0);  
  ellipseMode(CENTER);}  

void draw(){  
  for (int i=1; i<n; ++i){  
    for (int j=0; j<i; ++j){  
      if (flag[i][j]){  
        line(x[i],y[i],x[j],y[j]);}}}}
```

`

Comment: I am not sure, if the ramsey-theory flag is appropriate; please remove if it is misleading.

Comment: I would guess that fat spiders are centered around closely neighboring points. A scatter plot of degree vs nearest neighbor distance might be revealing.